# Alternative text in Django forms for None value in DateField

Tags: django, django-forms

I'd like to display an alternative text (let's say 'any') for no or empty value in a DateField's TextInput widget.

My idea was to set the form field's initial value to 'any' and then check in its `clean_<field>()` method for this initial value and cleaning it back to `None`:

```
date_field = forms.DateField(initial='any', required=False)

def clean_date_field(self):
    data = self.cleaned_data['date_field']
    if data == 'any':
        data = None
    return data
```

Unfortunately, the `clean_<field>()` method is never called, I think because some date format validation takes place in advance and raises a `ValidationError` which will prevent the `clean_<field>()` method from ever being called.

Is there a simple way to display an alternative form field value for `None` using a `DateField`?

Any hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create custom field and override `to_python` method.
`to_python` will be called before field's clean, and you can convert `any` to `None` value there.

```
def to_python(self, value):
    if value == 'any':
        value = None
    return super(CustomField, self).to_python(value)
```

Also you can use HTML5 `placeholder`.